# How to allow access to my gcloud appengine apis using a specific port other than the default port 443

Tags: firewall, port-forwarding, google-app-engine

I've already tried to configure the firewall and I still can't access using the port other than the default port

Comment: Please check the ["Port Forwarding"](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#port_forwarding) paragraph of the documentation. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: yes, i already added it to app.yaml that way
network: forwarded ports: - 443: 42340 / tcp
it didn't work so I tried it another way
network: forwarded_ports: - 42340 / tcp

but I was also unsuccessful

Comment: could you share your configuration files and the firewall rule you used for this?